# JAVA write new row to .CSV file

Tags: java, file, csv, file-io, append

How can I write a new row of data to a .CSV file that already has data in it. So far my code just clears the file and doesn't actually write anything?

```
            BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        String fileString = "patients.csv";
        String fileLine = "";

        File file = new File(fileString);
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileString);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        while((fileLine = br.readLine()) != null){

            bw.write(fileLine);
        }


        br.close();
        bw.close();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Can you show input and expected output?

Comment: I want to write a new line of data to an existing .CSV file. The input comes from multiple JTextFields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify true in the constructor java FileWriter to know that the true and append be added to the end of the file if you place it does not overwrite information

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileString,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to a file using FileWriter then use this [Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

As per Javadocs

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning.

But, back to your code, you will only need to write new data to the `FileWriter` and not rewrite existing data.